# Stop message upon completion of fsolve

Tags: matlab

Whenever fsolve finishes, it gives the output

```
Equation solved.

fsolve completed because the vector of function values is near zero
as measured by the default value of the function tolerance, and
the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient.

<stopping criteria details>
```

Is it possible to stop this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try setting the options:

```
opts = optimset('Diagnostics','off', 'Display','off');
[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun, x0, opts);
```